# Não sei como fazer INSERT de tabelas nxn

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE pacotes 
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    nome VARCHAR(100),
    valor FLOAT,
    percentual_max_desconto TINYINT,
);

CREATE TABLE pontos_turisticos 
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,  
    id_endereco INT,
    nome VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_endereco) REFERENCES enderecos(id)
);


CREATE TABLE pacotes_pontos_turisticos 
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    id_ponto_turistico INT,
    id_pacote INT ,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_ponto_turistico) REFERENCES pontos_turisticos(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_pacote) REFERENCES pacotes(id),
);
```

Preciso fazer o `INSERT` mas não sei como.

Comment: o que seria "nxn"? cardinalidade "n..n", é isso? aliás, é `mysql` ou `sql-server`?

Comment: n para n segundo meu professor mais eu consegui arrumar eu precisava fazer um select dentro de outro select.

Comment: inclua os pontos turísticos; inclua os pacotes; estabeleça a relação entre pacotes e pontos turísticos ao incluir linhas em `pacotes_pontos_turisticos`